Integrating Microsoft Entra ID OAuth2 with BFF Pattern for React, Spring Cloud Gateway, and Spring Boot REST API while also calling Graph API
I'm working on a project where I'm using a BFF (Backend for Frontend) pattern with the following components:

React Front-End: Communicates exclusively with a Spring Cloud Gateway.
Spring Cloud Gateway: Acts as a proxy/router, handles the login/authentication flow using Microsoft Entra ID (configured as an OAuth2 client).
Spring Boot REST API: A downstream service that acts as an OAuth2 resource server, validating JWTs issued by Microsoft Entra ID.

Setup Overview:

The React app redirects to /login/oauth2/{registration_id} on the Gateway to initiate login.
The Gateway handles the authentication with Entra ID using a custom scope (api://[clientid]/access_as_user).
The Gateway passes the access token (JWT) as a Bearer token to the REST API via token relay.
The REST API uses this JWT for authorization, ensuring the user is authenticated.

Problem:
I need the REST API to make calls to SharePoint through the Microsoft Graph API on behalf of the authenticated user. However, the access token relayed to the REST API has a custom audience (my API) and is not valid for Microsoft Graph, which requires a different token with Graph-specific scopes.
The REST API only receives the access token from the Authorization header and does not have the refresh token, so it can't exchange the current token for one with Graph-specific scopes. While the Gateway could perform the exchange, it can't pass a Graph audience token to the REST API without breaking signature validation.
Question:
How can I securely implement this pattern where:

The Spring Boot REST API remains secured against my custom audience (Entra ID application).
The REST API can make authorized Graph API calls on behalf of the logged-in user.
The BFF pattern is preserved, maintaining the current architecture.

Is there a recommended way to handle this token exchange or structure the system to support both custom API security and Graph API calls?

In the OAuth2 BFF configuration, you should request the scope to have the expected audience (yes, that looks strange to request a scope to declare an audience, but after all, you chose Microsoft...) and the scope for the graph API. Scope is a list of strings.

Thanks for the reply. So I attempted to request both scopes when requesting the token as my first idea but Entra doesn't seem to like this. To be fair I was trying https://graph.microsoft.com/.default. Perhaps this is the wrong scope. Ultimately I just need to able to make sharepoint calls through graph (Graph API for sharepoint access not directly into sharepoint online's rest API). In that case what would my complete scope list look like. Currently I just have my api://[clientid]/access_as_user, openid

Be careful that scope is a space-delimited list of strings (not comma-separated). You should have commas only in Spring application properties if posting values on a single line and without quotes (if using YAML, you may put a value per line with a leading -). Also, there are many unnatural tricks with MS and I had to write a special chapter for it in my docs. Check that you meet all conditions I listed there.

I wasn't aware of those limitations. My scope is defined all on one line comma separated in an application.yaml so I think that part is fine. I tried specifying a scope for SP through graph (as listed in my API permission in Entra) and I ran into an error like this AADSTS28003: Provided value for the input parameter scope cannot be empty when requesting an access token using the provided. Googling around seems to indicate that you can't use the same token for two different APIs with the suggestion being that you have to grab a new token with a different audience/scope

Have you followed the link just above? Are you using V2 tokens?

Hi yes. I followed the link and had a read. Everything there looks in line with how I have my things setup (at least for the parts that are relevant to what I'm doing) I am not sure if I'm using v1 or v2 tickets but I'm requesting the token at /oauth2/v2.0/ so I assume this means its a v2 token.

So, you have not checked and are probably using V1 tokens...
